# PHP: Problems converting "’" character from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, iconv

I'm having some issues with using PHP to convert ISO-8859-1 database content to UTF-8. I am running the following code to test:

```
// Connect to a latin1 charset database 
// and retrieve "Georgia O’Keeffe", which contains a "’" character
$connection = mysql_connect('*****', '*****', '*****');
mysql_select_db('*****', $connection);
mysql_set_charset('latin1', $connection);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT notes FROM categories WHERE id = 16', $connection);
$latin1Str = mysql_result($result, 0);
$latin1Str = substr($latin1Str, strpos($latin1Str, 'Georgia'), 16);

// Try to convert it to UTF-8
$utf8Str = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $latin1Str);

// Output both
var_dump($latin1Str);
var_dump($utf8Str);
```

When I run this in Firefox's source view, making sure Firefox's encoding setting is set to "Western (ISO-8859-1)", I get this:

[image: asd]

So far, so good. The first output contains that weird quote and I can see it correctly because it's in ISO-8859-1 and so is Firefox.

After I change Firefox's encoding setting to "UTF-8", it looks like this:

[image: asd]

Where did the quote go? Wasn't `iconv()` supposed to convert it to UTF-8?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK is not a character in ISO-8859-1.  It is a character in [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), as 0x92.  The actual ISO-8859-1 character 0x92 is a rarely-used [C1 control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) called "Private Use 2".

> It is very common to mislabel
>   Windows-1252 text data with the
>   charset label ISO-8859-1. Many web
>   browsers and e-mail clients treat the
>   MIME charset ISO-8859-1 as
>   Windows-1252 characters in order to
>   accommodate such mislabeling but it is
>   not standard behaviour and care should
>   be taken to avoid generating these
>   characters in ISO-8859-1 labeled
>   content.

It appears that this is what's happening here.  Change "ISO-8859-1" to "windows-1252".

Comment: Wow, I did that and I see the U+2019 in UTF-8 mode! But is it safe to use "windows-1252" to convert a large amount of data from "ISO-8859-1" to "UTF-8"? In other words, will all of the ISO-8859-1 characters still convert correctly?

Comment: The characters 0x80-0x9F will not convert correctly.  But these are control characters which are almost never used.

Comment: @mattalexx If you check the string for characters in that range and find any, it's a good bet that the string is encoded in Windows-1252.  If you **don't** find any characters in that range, it's more likely to be ISO-8859-1.

Comment: If i could give you +10, I would. Been banging my head against a brick wall for weeks with this and your answer solved what other suggestions couldn't

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your problem, supposing that your page header `charset` is utf-8:

```
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password);
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($connection);
$flagChange = mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);
echo "The character set is: $charset</br>mysql_set_charset result:$flagChange</br>";
```

Comment: Would this still work if properly updated to `mysqli`?