# Translating ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 problem

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1

One of my projects pulls a document from the web and reads it. This document is provided by a third party and will not change (the content will, but formatting and other stuff will not). 
The problem is that this document includes content copy and pasted from Word, which is UTF-8, however the document is encoded in ISO-8858-1, so these characters get saved to the database as '?'.

If I past over the text, and re-encode it in UTF-8, instead of getting the smartquotes and em dashes, I just get two garbage characters.

How can I convert this ISO-8859-1 document with UTF-8 character back into UTF-8 so it can be displayed as it was originally created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here: [PHP: Problems converting "’" character from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714061/php-problems-converting-character-from-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8)

The server claims it's serving up ISO-8859-1, but it's really Windows-1252, which converts to UTF-8 without a problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
$fixed = mb_convert_encoding($broken, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1");
```

don't know if it'd properly handle UTF-8 embedded in 8859, but that's the "normal" way of doing it. Man page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). Give it a whirl and see if things get cleaner or more mangled.

Comment: Reverse the order of the 2nd and 3rd parameters and this would solve it.

Comment: Solved my problem by using mb_convert_encoding($broken, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, ISO 8859-1 is 8bit-transparent. Therefore, you can just decode the content with [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) or [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

I'm not sure what "I past over the text" means, but if this is really UTF-8 designated as ISO 8859-1, try eliminating all intermediate text manipulation. If that still fails, please provide an example of a (short) input document. Chances are it's not actually UTF-8 designated as ISO 8859-1.

Comment: by passing over the text means I'm using mb_convert_encoding, iconv, or utf8_encode, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Malfist Well, than the input is not ISO8859-1

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714061/php-problems-converting-character-from-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8